# Why is Microsoft Word changing page numbers on my Table of Contents back to 0?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table of contents with page numbers and after page 8, the table of contents automatically is starting pages back at 0, 1, 2, etc. This is what it looks like

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
1
2
...
Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have a "Section Break" after page 8 instead of a "Page Break"?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a section break after page 8 and new section has page numbering settings set to start at 0.

Position the cursor after page 8, go to **Insert** tab, open **Page Number** drop-down and click **Format Page Numbers...** from drop-down. There select option to **Continue from previous section**. 
Take a look at the following picture:
[image: Page Number Format]

After that update Table of Contents.

Answer (score 0):

As the others suggested, this is likely due to a section break. In my document I didn't need a break there, so I removed the section break and refreshed the ToC, after which my page numbers were as I expected. Stipo's answer would also work, where you need to keep the section break (I didn't need it)